# get the distinct element(eg: ID) from student detail where collection of student details are inside another array using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

**//Model**

```
public class StudentDetails
    {
            
            public int Contact { get; set; }
            public string Summary { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
            public long ID { get; set; }
    
        }
```

**//controller**

public async Task AddStudDetails([FromBody] StudentDetails[] studentDetails){}

Comment: I tried foreach loop but using that will iterate my rest of the implementation. So if anyone has any other solution please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LINQ to do this:

```csharp
var distinctResults = studentDetails.DistinctBy(student => student.ID).ToArray();
```

This'll yield an array of all the students where no two students have the same ID.

you'd also have to add a `using System.Linq;` to your imports :)

#### Edit

if you have a `StudentDetails[][]` as an input (array of arrays of StudentDetails) and you still want to use LINQ then this would be one way of doing it

```csharp
StudentDetails[][] myArrArr = ...;
myArrArr
    .Aggregate(new List<StudentDetails>(), (resultList, studentDetails) => resultList
        .Concat(studentDetails)
        .DistinctBy(s => s.ID)
        .ToList());
```

however using a simple dictionary may be faster and less resource intensive

```csharp
StudentDetails[][] myArrArr = ...;
Dictionary<long, StudentDetails> distinctStudents = new();
foreach (StudentDetails[] array in myArrArr)
{
    foreach (StudentDetails details in array)
    {
        distinctStudents.TryAdd(details.ID, details);
    }
}
var result = distinctStudents.Values.ToArray();
```

#### Edit 2

I think I finally understood your question, if you just want to extract a single property of a collection of objects you could just do a simple `Select()`

```csharp
var allIds = studentDetails.Select(student => student.ID).ToArray();
```

Comment: here student detail is a single object and where we fetch only the distinct IDs. But if that student detail is an element of another array will the same implementation works? @Frederik

Comment: public async Task AddStudDetails([FromBody] StudentDetails[] studentDetails){} This is how I will be creating my request body. its an array of array. So I need to fetch the distinct ID from each of the student object

Comment: @user19305733 I updated the answer for the case of nested arrays

Comment: Although I don't see where there would be a nested array (array of arrays) in the case of `Task AddStudDetails([FromBody] StudentDetails[] studentDetails)`. This function takes a simple `StudentDetails[]` called `studentDetails` from the body (probably of a web request) as a parameter. The `[FromBody]` is simply an [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/) applied to the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
var stud = from s in studentDetails select s.ID;
```

figured out the code I was looking for. Hope this will be helpful to others too.